# Adding raster image to Raster field with Python?

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-desktop

I have a feature class with with field that is of Raster data type.

I want to add an image to each record in the feature class.

Is it possible to use Python to add the image to the Raster field for each record?

I've been searching but can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a tool for adding images (you might want to suggest one over at [ArcGIS ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/)), but you can programmatically add attachments to each feature with [Add Attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014v000000). This isn't quite the same as an image in the attribute table, but you don't have to manually add potentially lots of images.

This tool is fairly similar to Add Join. You need a table containing a join field (maybe OID) and a path to the image.

Comment: Yeah, I did see the add attachments tool, and it might be the way to go. One question. If I add the attachments to a personal geodatabase and then copy the entire contents of the personal geodatabase into an enterprise SDE database, will all the attachments follow? Basically, with add attachments, are the images actually stored in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure if they will be copied over (I would guess so), but the images are stored in the GDB. You can move/edit/delete the original images and it won't have any impact. The help for `Add Attachments` has some information on this.